# Rotating Servo Motor using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, servo, pwm, loop

Using arduino, I'm trying to rotate a 360 servo that will move clockwise 5 seconds,pause and counterclockwise for 5 seconds and then completely stop. However, my servo just continuously keeps on rotating in one direction. Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Please post your code and circuit, otherwise we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

you have not put your code here so i can not understand it properly.From what i understand you must have put your code for rotating the servo motor 5 times in void loop. Don't do that put loop for rotating servo 5 time in setup.

void loop run continuously so it must be rotating 5 time then again 5 time and so on.